# Regexp (not in string) in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Okie, I have the following files:

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  12 al  staff   408B Feb 28 11:36 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 40 al  staff   1.3K Feb 28 10:07 ../
drwxr-xr-x   3 al  staff   102B Oct 19 20:38 Install OS X Yosemite.app/
-rw-r--r--   1 al  staff     7B Dec 15 13:35 file1
-rw-r--r--   1 al  staff     4B Dec 15 13:35 file2
-rw-r--r--   1 al  staff    11B Dec 15 13:35 file3.part
-rw-r--r--   1 al  staff     0B Feb 28 11:36 file4.art
-rwxr-xr-x   1 al  staff   1.9K Feb 28 11:35 show.pl*
drwxr-xr-x   2 al  staff    68B Feb 28 10:07 test1/
drwxr-xr-x   6 al  staff   204B Feb 28 10:12 test2/
drwxr-xr-x   3 al  staff   102B Feb 28 10:07 test3/
drwxr-xr-x   3 al  staff   102B Feb 28 10:12 test4/
```

Now I need a regexp that will do the following:

3 or more characters (to omit . and ..) of any type *NOT* ending in the string .part (but ending in anything else is OK).

The following almost works, but it will not match .app and .art (which it should).

```
print $file =~ m/^.{3,}[^(\.part)]$/i;
```

And please believe me when I say... I have TRIED (for a loooong time)

Comment: Why are you so determined to write it in a single regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a  negative lookahead assertion at the start.

```
print $file =~ m/^(?!.*\.part$).{3,}/i;
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vW6jU8/3)

Asserts that the string going to be matched won't contain `.part` string at the last. If yes, then match the string which has three or more characters. `$` asserts that we are at the end.